# Spotify Web API: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`. I'm trying to using `this.setState` to so rendering some tracks onto but limit to only 9 tracks want to see if doing everything correctly.

Here Code Below:

```
import React from 'react';
require('dotenv').config();

// My Steps: //

// 1. Want to fetch for KD Rusha Top Ablums on Spoitify Done
// 2. Limit them to only 9 tracks
// 3. Add play button on top of each track to play 30 sec of the Song


// GO TO SPOTIFY AND GETTING KD RUSHA TOP ABLUMS lIMIT TO 9 SONGS
// WHEN YOU CLICK ON TOP OF THE ABLUMS A PLAY BUTTON ICON WILL SHOW TO INDICATE THAT YOU CAN PLAY 30 SECONDS OF SONG

export default class SpotifyComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       artist: null,
    };
}

componentWillMount() {

var request = new Request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5JLWikpo5DFPqvIRi43v5y/', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: new Headers({
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Authorization': 'Access Token Here'
  })

});

  fetch(request)// fetch the Spotify date from KD Rusha Account
    .then(function(response){
      var result = response.json()
        this.setState({// State artist albums
          albums: result,
          selectedTrack: [0]
        });

    console.log(this.setState);
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }
    return response.json();
  });
}

  render(){
    return(
      <ul className="spotify-cantainer">

      </ul>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `.bind` or the fat arrow syntax `=>` do declare your promise callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

.then(function(response){

Should be .then((response) => {

If you don't use arrow functions you lose this context.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the `then` the context of `this` changes and no longer refers to the component. You have a couple of options to resolve this.

You could assign `this` to a variable and then use the variable: e.g.

```
var self = this;

request(...)
.then(function(response) {
   self.setState(...)
})
```

Or, if you are able to with your application you could use arrow functions instead of normal functions. e.g.

```
request(...)
.then((response) => {
   this.setState(...)
})
```

The reason for this is arrow function, by default bind to the scope. You can read more here: https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/#functionality-lexical-scoping-this

Answer (score 0):

this generally happens when we get the response code `403` which means forbidden according to Spotify's API documentation.
to solve this problem just add the scope of the response you want to get in the authentication URL and it will start working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).